# How to use charts or graphs developed using d3node on client side

Tags: d3.js, server-side-rendering, jsdom

We have a very heavy web application that showing charts and graphs using d3.

The issue in the current solution:

1. Heavy data transfer to the browser
2. All calculation happening on the client side
3. Performance of the browser is getting hit

I was thinking of moving all such steps to server side using d3-node.

I read several articles regarding doing stuff on the server side but what I am not sure how will I transfer the output to the client side.

So my requirements are:

1. I have some 10-15 charts and graphs on UI
2. I will do a separate ajax call to the server
3. Server will create charts on the server side
4. Server will return HTML that I can embed in my UI sections.

Please help with a better architecture or method. Thanks.

Comment: You can try reducing the number of points on server side. Checkout this reduction algorithm: https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18936/A-C-Implementation-of-Douglas-Peucker-Line-Appro. Returning html from server wouldn't be a good option. You can return a json and keep some sort of a limiting queue on UI side. Similar question I have answered before: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53399383/incremental-price-graph-approximation/53456851#53456851

Comment: you can serve the result as an SVG, but that results in bigger files then your dataset files. If the chart need interaction you can build some of it in the SVG, forceSim or tree animation won't work. What kind of charts and how large is the dataset